# Proving by induction that strictly lower triangular matrix is nilpotent

Tags: matrices, induction, solution-verification, nilpotence

> Let matrix $A \in \mathbb{K}^{n \times n}$ have the property $a_{ij} = 0$ for $1 \leq i \leq j \leq n$. Show that $A^n = 0$.

Proof by induction:

**Base Case:**

for $n=2: 
   A=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   0 & 0 \\
   a_{21} & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right]$

So $A^2 = \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   0 & 0 \\
   a_{21} & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right] \cdot 
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   0 & 0 \\
   a_{21} & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right] = 
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right]$

**Inductive Hypothesis(IH):**

Assume $A^n = 0$ holds true for some $n$.

**Inductive Step:**

$n \rightarrow  n+1$, to show: $A^{n+1} = 0 $

$A^{n+1} = A^n \cdot A =^{IH} 0 \cdot A = 0$

It seems to be too simple. Is it correct to prove this by induction?

Comment: First check if your inductive step really takes you from $n=2$ to $n=3$. Can you see what the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, induction *is* certainly a good way to try and prove the result. However, there are some problems with your attempt to do so.

One problem is that the $\ A\ $ in your induction hypothesis is an $\ n\times n\ $ matrix, whereas the one in your induction step has to be an *arbitrary* $\ (n+1)\times(n+1)\ $ matrix satisfying the stated conditions. That means it *cannot* be the *same* $\ A\ $ as the one appearing in the induction hypothesis.

To fix the proof, your induction hypothesis must be something like $"\ A^n = 0\ $ for *all* strictly lower triangular $\ n\times n\ $ matrices $\ A\ $."  Also, in the induction step, an identity you will probably find useful is
$$
\pmatrix{B&0 _{n\times1}\\b^\top&0}^k=\pmatrix{B^k&0 _{n\times1}\\b^\top B^{k-1}
&0}\ ,
$$
for any $\ n\times n\ $ matrix $\ B\ $ and $\ n\times1\   $ column vector $\ b\ $.

Comment: $\pmatrix{B&0 _{n\times1}\\b^\top&0}^k=\pmatrix{B^k&0 _{n\times1}\\b^\top B^{k-1}
&0}\ $

How did you get from one side of the equation to the other?

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like this:
$\pmatrix{0_{1\times(n-1)}&0\\B&0_{(n-1)\times1}}^k$. Since a Matrix B is wrapped around in zeros.

Comment: The identity is clearly true for $\ k=1\ $, and if it holds for some given $\ k\ $, then
\begin{align}
\pmatrix{B&0 _{n\times1}\\b^\top&0}^{k+1}&= \pmatrix{B&0 _{n\times1}\\b^\top&0}\pmatrix{B^k&0 _{n\times1}\\b^\top B^{k-1}
&0}\\
&= \pmatrix{B^{k+1}&0 _{n\times1}\\b^\top B^k&0}\ ,
\end{align}
so the identity holds for every $\ k\ $ by induction.

Comment: The point of the identity is that if $\ A\ $ is *any* strictly lower triangular $\ (n+1)\times (n+1)\ $ matrix, then it *must be* true that
$$
A= \pmatrix{B&0 _{n\times1}\\b^\top&0}\ ,
$$
where $\ B\ $ is a *strictly lower triangular* $\ n\times n\ $ matrix.  While it's also true that
$$
A= \pmatrix{0_{1\times n}& 0\\C&0_{n\times1}}\ ,$$ where $\ C\ $ is an $\ n\times n\ $ matrix, $\ C_{11}=A_{21}\ $ is not necessarily $0$ in this case, so $\ C\ $ is not necessarily strictly lower triangular, so I don't see how that decomposition would be of any use for proving the result by induction.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to deduce the $n=3$ case from $n=2$ that you describe, this happens:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
a_{21} & 0 & 0 \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & 0
\end{pmatrix}^{3} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
a_{21} & 0 & 0 \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & 0
\end{pmatrix}^{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
a_{21} & 0 & 0 \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
You can't conclude that $A^2 = 0$ because this matrix is $3\times 3$ and not $2\times 2$ like your previous case.